# Posting to correct Instagram Account with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to post images to Instagram app from MY app.

Please note my app does not use Instagram API or log in to users' Instagram Account.

```
let sharingImage = button.backgroundImage(for: [])
let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [sharingImage as AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)

avc.excludedActivityTypes = [.addToReadingList,.airDrop,.assignToContact,.copyToPasteboard,.openInIBooks,.postToFacebook,.postToFlickr,.postToTencentWeibo,.postToTwitter,.postToVimeo,.postToWeibo,.saveToCameraRoll,.message,.mail,.print]
if let wPPC = avc.popoverPresentationController {
    wPPC.sourceView = followUsButton
}
self.present(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am logged into my Instagram App with multiple accounts. Upon share from MY app, Instagram tries to post to the account 'A' which is currently logged in (inside the Instagram app). This makes sense.

However, if I now switch to the Instagram app and switch to account 'B' inside it, go back to MY app and then try to share again, it continues to try to post to Account 'A'.

The only way to fix it, is to kill MY app and start it again and then it loads the correct currently logged in account 'B'.

Is there a way to programmatically reload the correct Insta account while sharing?

Comment: Did you test it with the one of the native iOS apps like *Photos* too?

Comment: Photos app has the same WRONG behavior.

Comment: If you are able to share boilerplate code of HOW you are posting using the activityviewcontroller this would be very helpful.

Comment: @JulianSilvestri Posted

Comment: Just in case, when you say that the problem occurs when switching accounts, do you mean

In MY app, you immediately try to post from the same ViewController?
You move to a parent View (hence destroying the old one)back , then to the same view as 1/?

Comment: That is obviously an Instagram (or eventually iOS) bug, not sure why you offered bounty for that...

Comment: Have you tried destroying the activity controller upon goint to background app State and that way you have to reinitialize it and it might get your current logged in user

Comment: @IvanIčin Looking for a workaround.

Comment: @ADProgress does not work.

Comment: @Kashif I have added a workaround for you hope it will solve the issue until Apple solves it on their side.

Comment: if you save your photo/video in photos app first than after you can direct post to instagram with URL Schemme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a workaround however might be your only choice at the moment as you see that even native Photos has the same issue so it is rather down to Apple to fix it.

In your application's `Info.plist`, add a boolean key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` with the value `YES`. See the [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) for more information.

This way the app is getting terminated when enters a background state and once you go back to it it will get reloaded. The user might not notice the difference.

Perhaps before killing the app you could add some interface state saving function in:

```
 optional func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)
```

I don't know how your app is laid out but you could create a singleton class which could be implementing Codable and keep tracking all the app state variables which would have a save and load function. Saving would be triggered upon termination and loading when app is launching.

I hope it will help in some way.

EDIT1: Should work in iOS 13
Below this code should work and terminate your app however it is not recommended and you might face an issue when uploading to AppStore. I guess you can challenge the rejection with the Apple review team by explaining that they have a bug in the SDK and point them to the problem.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
    UIApplication.shared.perform(#selector(NSXPCConnection.suspend))
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
      exit(0)
     }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best workaround so far. Though, will be a lot of work.

Comment: @Kashif Perhaps a saving class would be a good option here. See my update on the answer.

Comment: It seems `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` has now been deprecated by Apple. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Kashif I have updated the answer hope it helps however might give you issues when uploading to the AppStore

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, I doubt.

`UIActivityViewController` doesn't give you control over the user's login status (which is why it's interesting to use). IMO, that's a bug on Apple side. So, unless there's a secret way to clear the authorisation tokens that the iOS runtime has stored within your app memory, I don't see how you could possibly achieve what you want.

Plus, if Photos app has the same behaviour, that's not a good sign...

Just in case, when you say that the problem occurs when switching accounts, do you mean

1. In MY app, you immediately try to post from the same ViewController?
2. You move to a parent View (hence destroying the old one)back , then to the same view as 1/?

Do you have the same result in both case? I am asking because when instantiating a new `UIActivityViewController` in a new view, the runtime might fetch the new user login profile, while if you instantiate it from the same view that was used to post from the old account, it might not do so (hence it'll use the old login)

Comment: I tried closing ViewController and opening it again but that does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: ok, that's a bug. IMO on iOS side. If you're part of a dev team, i suggest you log a bug report, and get confirmation from Apple Support, so that there's no impact on your deliverables. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is iOS issue not specific to your app.